# Where to create AnExampleReactPackage module while creating a native module in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am creating a new native module for react native as per the documentation given [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html). According to it, we have to register the module by creating [AnExampleReactPackage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#register-the-module) module. But I don't know where exactly in my project path do I have to create this module. I have tried the same location where `MainReactPackage` is created, i.e

```
ReactAndroid\src\main\jave\com\facebook\react\shell\MainReactPackage.java
```

but failed. So where do I create this module or is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `ReactPackage` anywhere inside your Android project and import it in the `MainReactPackage.java`.

I prefer creating all the `ReactNative` Modules in the same folder. So, I create modules like `com/example/modules/AnExampleReactPackage`.